# Is there a penalty risk from Google with a page containing 70+ outbound links to high quality sites

Tags: seo, nofollow, penalty, directory

I have a page that links to about 70+ high-quality websites.

The page looks like this:

```
<a href="website#1">website name</a> - info about the site (~20 words)
<a href="website#1">website name</a> - info about the site (~20 words)
<a href="website#1">website name</a> - info about the site (~20 words)
...
```

I'm afraid maybe Google will penalize me for that. Should I `nofollow` these links?

Answer (score 1):

The **short answer** is no if those links are natural (not trying to manipulate [SERPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_results_page)).

### When `rel="nofollow"` should be used?

`rel="nofollow"` should be used in such cases:

- forum posts
- blog comments
- paid links, sponsored links
- *etc.*

With `rel="nofollow"`, you do not endorse the target website, which would be contradictory with the aim of your page. I mean, you probably list these links because you reckon that they are of interest to your visitors.

Reference: [When Do You Use Nofollow on Links?](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/use-nofollow-links/245241/)

### Considerations about numerous links

In the past, there was a suggested vague maximum of 100 links per page, but this was only for crawling technical reasons; it was not a threshold beyond which a penalty was assigned.

Reference: [How Many Links Is Too Many?](https://moz.com/blog/how-many-links-is-too-many)

### About penalties

Remember that as long as you do things honestly and build your sites naturally with the aim of providing the best contents and user experience, you will not get a penalty from search engines. You may loose some page ranking if your are not good in [white-hat SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization#White_hat_versus_black_hat_techniques), but this is not a "penalty" *stricto sensu*.